# Pagina PHP error 500 despues de borrar accidentalmente carpeta vendor

Tags: php

necesito ayuda para una novata.

Tengo acceso a una pagina web hecha en PHP, borre por equivocación la carpeta de vendor, en mi local tenia una copia del proyecto entero por lo que volvi a subirla pero el sitio no funciona.

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Accede al log de errores ahi se grabó el texto asociado al fallo exacto que ocurrió

Comment: @BetaM tengo entendido que ese archivo se crea en el directorio donde esta la página. No hay ningun error_log y el que esta dentro de una carpeta ErrorLogs esta vacio

Comment: En algunos servidores se crea un log de errores en la carpeta del script que falla. Puede estar fallando un script que no necesariamente esté en la carpeta principal del sitio. Es extraño que habiendo restaurado el sitio con tu copia local no funcione ... puede que realmente no tuvieras una copia exacta del sitio. Algunos hosting tienen servicio de backup, si contactas con ellos desde la página de soporte (lo mejor es vía chat, en inglés) puedes pedirle que te restauren el sitio y lo hacen. Puede que el backup de ellos esté un poco atrasado (un par de días o una semana) pero funciona seguro.